# Potential problem with the "Edward" hat

Tags: discussion, status-completed, badges, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

So the "Edward" hat on the Winter Bash page says that we have to earn the Curious badge. However, I have already earned it on one of the sites before the Winter Bash and haven't gotten the hat yet. Do I have to earn the Curious badge on a different site?

Comment: Triggers generally are for actions completed during winter bash. Having the badge isn't the trigger. The trigger is the same as the badge. Subtle but important difference.

Comment: @Catija Does that mean that users who've already joined every site in the network can't earn the Gimme Space hat?

Comment: @SonictheK-DayHedgehog Mods and high-rep users might have a problem with the Carmen hat as well.

Comment: Y'all... there's always hats that not everyone can get.... on the same site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trigger is the same as the badge - which means :

> Each day during a 5-day period, ask a positively scored question and have no negatively scored, closed or deleted questions.

Having the badge already isn't the same thing as qualifying for it during Winter Bash. So, to get this hat, you have to start asking questions, one per day, and have them all be well-received. You should be able to earn the hat even on sites where you've already earned the badge - **the trigger isn't to earn the badge** - it's just the same as it.

Comment: The description of the hat *very clearly* states that it's related to earning the badge, not to just meeting its criteria. Perhaps it should be reworded to something like "Meet the criteria for the Curious badge" or the actual trigger as you quoted.

Comment: Also, this means that if one has earned, say, three qualifying days toward the badge in the past, but meets the last two during WB, they'll earn the badge but not earn the hat. This means that the description of the hat as on the WB site - "Earn the Curious badge" - is incorrect.

Comment: That's just the short description. The long description says nothing about the badge.

Answer (score 4):

I have changed the short description on [the Edward](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/edward) hat to make this more clear:

[image: Screenshot of new description: "Ask only good questions for 5 days"]

> Edward, oh Edward
> short description misleading
> hopefully more clear?

Comment: Okay, so does that mean that the curious badge is disregarded?

Comment: The hat itself is not connected to awarding the curious badge. Just uses the same criteria.