# Another potential problem with the Edward hat

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash-2020

I think I meet the [criteria for the Edward hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357933/295232):

> Each day during a 5-day period, ask a positively scored question and have no negatively scored, closed or deleted questions.

| Date | Question(s) |
| --- | --- |
| December 20th | [Does the '10' in some of the hat triggers mean anything?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358428/295232) |
| December 19th | [Chat username highlighter is too eager](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358345/295232) |
| December 18th | [Some topbar items aren't properly 'selected' when using the Tab key to navigate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358276/295232) |
| December 17th | [Winter Bash 2020 hat names & references explained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358178/295232) |
| December 16th | ['1 new hat' notification doesn't go away](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357921/295232) and [Winter Bash 2020 hat list 👒 🎩](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357915/295232) |

I'm pretty sure I would've gotten the Curious badge if I didn't already have it; does Edward not like me having asked *two* questions on the same day? I checked but I don't have any deleted questions.

Comment: (The December 20th might end up being closed (it has two close votes now) but it has been 'positive' for a few hours now; long enough to exclude any caching problems.)

Comment: Your december 16 posts are awfully close to 00:00Z so perhaps a time zone issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You did not, at the time you posted your question, qualify for the hat yet. The hat is awarded once you have a track record of 5 **complete** days. You won’t have such a track record until the 21st, once the 20th is over.

Now that midnight UTC has been reached and it is now Monday, 21 December, you have been awarded the hat:

[image: Winter Bash dialog showing Glorfindel’s hat collection, with the Edward hat selected and showing it was awarded on Meta.SE]